# Анимация списка

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation

https://refresh.study

На этом сайте, в разделе "Stay Organised", существует анимация списка (A Space for...). Дело в том, что мне необходимо реализовать похожую анимацию, но как это сделать, ума не приложу. Поэтому надеюсь на вашу помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайте это двигается скриптом, я сделал на `@keyframes`, а верстку прямо с сайта и взял:

```css
.list {
  animation: slideUp 4s forwards;
  --offset: 1%;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  0%  {transform: translateY(0%)}
  10% {transform: translateY(0%)}
  20% {transform: translateY(calc(20% + var(--offset)))}
  22% {transform: translateY(20%)}
  30% {transform: translateY(20%)}
  40% {transform: translateY(calc(40% + var(--offset)))}
  42% {transform: translateY(40%)}
  50% {transform: translateY(40%)}
  60% {transform: translateY(calc(60% + var(--offset)))}
  62% {transform: translateY(60%)}
  70% {transform: translateY(60%)}
  80% {transform: translateY(calc(80% + var(--offset)))}
  82% {transform: translateY(80%)}
  90% {transform: translateY(80%)}
  100% {transform: translateY(80%)}
}

.container1 {
  display: flex;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
}

.cropper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: .25em;
}

.item {
  padding-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.dot {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
}

html {
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="container1">
  <div>A Space for </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="cropper">
      <div class="list">
        <div class="item">everything</div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="dot" style="background-color: rgb(255, 45, 85);"></div>Thailand</div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="dot" style="background-color: rgb(255, 204, 0);"></div>Shopping</div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="dot" style="background-color: rgb(76, 217, 100);"></div>Work</div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="dot" style="background-color: rgb(0, 122, 255);"></div>Julius</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</h2>
```